# avoid select case on string value

Tags: .net, vb.net, coding-style, switch-statement

I read a lot about "clean code" and "design pattern" and they say to avoid "switch/select case" in the code. They say "use polymorphism" or the "strategy pattern".

How can I avoid a "select case"(VB.Net) on a string value with these concept?

```
select case value

  case "abc"
     method1()

  case "def"
     method2()

end select
```

even if I build a factory that return an object depending on the value of the string, the "select case" statement still...

Comment: These days Dependency Injection replaces serious factories. Your factory can be an XML file, which you can edit without recompiling code.

Comment: Can you give example or external link?

Comment: Check this project. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26466/Dependency-Injection-using-Spring-NET

Comment: that's overkill for the need of this post... thanks

Comment: Somehow the idea is that a case statement to create the proper object is more contained.  I kind of agree.

Comment: This is up to you, what you use. We don't know scope of your project, etc. For small project, where there are 3,4,5 strategies, a strategy pattern is sufficient. I worked on the project in which control factory generated hundreds of controls - we needed dependency injection. But there is nothing wrong with using CASE or IF when appropriate. You need to think, of scope, maintainability, feature development, etc., and have appropriate approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the methods take the same number and type of parameters and the same return type, you can simply add them to a dictionary, like this:

```
Dim methods = New Dictionary(Of String, Action)
methods.Add("abc", AddressOf method1)
methods.Add("def", AddressOf method2)
```

And then invoke it like this

```
methods(value)()
```

Alternatively, for a more object-oriented approach, create an interface for a factory:

```
Interface FooFactory
    Function CreateFoo() As Foo
End Interface
```

And again, add them to a dictionary:

```
Dim factories = New Dictionary(Of String, FooFactory)
factories.Add("abc", New FooFactory1)
factories.Add("def", New FooFactory2)
```

And then invoke it like this

```
Dim foo = factories(value).CreateFoo()
```